# sass variables depending on media queries

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to assign variables based on media queries?

```
@mixin akuru($podi){
    $smallText: $podi;
}

$ress: (320px, 480px, 768px);
$smText: (0.85em, 0.85em, 0.85em);

$lngt: length($ress);
@for $i from 1 through $lngt {
    @media only screen and (min-width: nth($ress, $i) ) {
        @include akuru(#{($smText, $i)});
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your SASS code working correctly.

```
@mixin akuru($podi){
  font-size: $podi;
}

$ress: (320px, 480px, 768px);
$smText: (0.85em, 0.95em, 1.85em);

$lngt: length($ress);
@for $i from 1 through $lngt {
  @media only screen and (min-width: nth($ress, $i) ) {
      @include akuru(#{nth($smText, $i)});
  };
};
```

**Outputs**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  font-size: 0.95em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  font-size: 1.85em;
}
```

Comment: What was the mistake? `nth` ?

Comment: Yes, you were missing the `nth` that was all

Comment: instead of `font-size: $podi;` can I use `$smallText: $podi;` to assign a variable so that I will be able to use it elseware as  `font-size: $smallText`?